# Addind assembly to DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've got a problem, I want to run scalar-valued-function that will run my C# method that evaluate mathematical expression from text. To evaluate expression I want to use Jace.dll (Jace.NET 0.8.4). When trying to add this dll to database assebly I've got this errors:

Assembly 'Jace' references assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

```
Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10300, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 Assembly 'Jace' references assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e.', which is not present in the current database.
 SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly
 from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed 
(reason: version, culture or public key mismatch). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

Can someone help me solve this one ? I know that database have different version of mscorlib than Jace is needed. Because db is using newer one. Should I just insert this 2.0.5 version to db ?

Comment: 1) what SQL Server version and 2) what .Net version is your assembly targeting

Comment: 1) Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64)
2) .Net framework 4.5